# How do I get Django to treat my float number as a float instead of an int when it renders a query?

Tags: python, sql, django, python-3.x, postgresql

I'm using Python 3.7 and Django with PostGres 9.5.  I have the following Django query

```
qset = DomainTrackerStat.objects.annotate(
    result=F('num_negative_articles') / (F('num_negative_articles') + F('num_positive_articles'))
).filter(subreddit=subreddit,
         domain=domain,
         num_negative_articles__gt=settings.DOMAIN_NEGATIVE_ARTICLES_THRESHOLD,
         result__gt=settings.DOMAIN_NEGATIVE_ARTICLES_PCT)
```

The constant, "settings.DOMAIN_NEGATIVE_ARTICLES_PCT" is ".95", but when my query gets rendered, the SQL appears as "0".  If I make it "settings.DOMAIN_NEGATIVE_ARTICLES_PCT * 100" the query is rendered with "95" as the value, but taht of course, is not the value I want.

How do I get Django to interpret the value as a float -- i.e. teh correct value I'm going for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an [**`ExpressionWrapper`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#expressionwrapper-expressions), like:

```
from django.db.models import ExpressionWrapper, F, FloatField

DomainTrackerStat.objects.annotate(
    result=ExpressionWrapper(
        F('num_negative_articles') / (F('num_negative_articles') + F('num_positive_articles')),
        output_field=FloatField()
    )
)
```

Or for PostgreSql, we should use the [**`Cast(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#cast) operator on the operands:

```
from django.db.models import F, FloatField
from django.db.models.functions import Cast

DomainTrackerStat.objects.annotate(
    result=Cast(F('num_negative_articles'), output_field=FloatField()) /
        Cast(F('num_negative_articles') + F('num_positive_articles'), output_field=FloatField())
)
```

As the documentation says:

> `ExpressionWrapper` simply surrounds another expression and provides access to properties, such as `output_field`, that may not be available on other expressions. **`ExpressionWrapper` is necessary when using arithmetic on `F()` expressions with different types** as described in [*Using `F()` with annotations*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-with-annotations).

Comment: Thx, your change fixed the "0" -> ".95" issue but there is still another problem.  When "F('num_negative_articles') / (F('num_negative_articles') + F('num_positive_articles'))" gets rednered as PostGres SQL -- '"myproject_domaintrackerstat"."num_negative_articles" / ("myproject_domaintrackerstat"."num_negative_articles" + "myproject_domaintrackerstat"."num_positive_articles")', taht expression is either getting evaluated to "1" or "0".  It is not evaluated as a float as it should be.

Comment: @Dave: what if you apply the `ExpressionWrapper` on one of the operands? So that it is already a float before the division.

Comment: Yup that was the way to go.  Thx.  On a side note, I'm fairly new with Python and the Django framework, but that seems like quite a lot of work to do in order to have a simple math expression.

Comment: @Dave: well the problem is that PostgreSQL will perform an *integer* division if the two operands are integers, so you need to cast these to their *float* counterparts first.